# Empty config object in JS

Tags: react-native, gradle, fastlane, android-productflavors, react-native-config

Using RN 64.0 and fastlane, I have the following build command

```
desc 'Build the Staging Android application.'
    lane :build_staging do
      gradle(task: 'clean', project_dir: 'android/')
      gradle(task: 'assemble', flavor: "staging", build_type: 'release', project_dir: 'android/')
  end
```

In `app/build.gradle` I have added the env. config files like so:

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    stagingdebug: ".env.staging",
    stagingrelease: ".env.staging",
    productiondebug: ".env.production",
    productionrelease: ".env.production",
]
```

For some reason when I run the build command, in other words `fastlane android build_production`, and install the `apk` on a device, the config file is an empty object when being consumed from `import env from 'react-native-config';`

When I run `npx react-native run-android --variant stagingrelease"`, the app works as expected and gets the config.

Answer (score 1):

injecting hte env `gradle(...)` command on fastlane did the the trick. The expected behavior was for it to resolve the right file based on the `{{flavor}}{{build type}}` which doesn't seem to work with fastlane as of right now.

Solution:

```
gradle(task: 'assemble', flavor: "staging", build_type: 'Release', project_dir: 'android/', system_properties: {"ENVFILE": ".env.staging" })
```